# Background Task to record closing time of the Toast Notification and Write it in a file

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Toast notification have a "close button" in the upper right corner.I want to get the current time and the title of the Toast notification when user click that "close button" and write that time and title in the xml format in the file.

Comment: does your toast do anything if clicked normally, or does it just close when clicked?

Comment: it has to close if it is clicked anywhere.It has to trigger the task only if we click the close button

Comment: check out this page https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/ it might point you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the current time and the title of the Toast notification when user click that "close button"

Takarii's suggestion was on the right direction. The ToastNotification has [Dissmissed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.dismissed) event, it occurs when a toast notification leaves the screen, either by expiring or being explicitly dismissed by the user. You can add a timestamp to record the time.

> write that time and title in the xml format in the file.

You could refer to the official [XML DOM sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument) for details.

Comment: It was like event handler, I want it as a back ground Task

Comment: @visnusrinivasan You could send toast notification in background task and register this event in background task. It will work.